# SQL Group Entries With 3 Common Values And Return Further Detail from Latest Entry Only

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I have a table called Alarms. I would like to run a query that groups repeat alarms.

The table has the following fields:

Index,  Alarm,  Controller, Title,  Cleared Time,   SiteNum,    SiteName,   Occurred Time,  Accepted Time, Comments,    Status,

The result would be grouped by Alarm, Controller, SiteName and give a count.

I have achieved this using the following query:

```
SELECT Alarm, Controller, SiteNum, COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Alarms
FROM Alarms
GROUP BY Alarm, Controller, SiteNum
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

However i would like to include the 'Occurred Time' Result from the vary latest entry.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
MAX([Occurred Time]) AS LatestOccurrence
```

to the SELECT clause

Comment: That is the highest Occurred time, not the Occurred time of the last entry, although they may be the same.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help!